# Avoid browser cache in a java web-application

Tags: url, jakarta-ee, tomcat, caching, servlets

I am creating a project in `vaadin` which runs on `Tomcat`, but the question concerns generally a java web-application. The application consists of a number of modules, which all together comprise the application. I want to adjust it, so as the way the application runs to be determined by the url. Therefore I attach a parameter to the url, the url seems namely as:

`http:myproject/anything/foo?mode=sth`.

I extract the parameter in the method `onRequestStart()`:

```
String param = request.getParameter("mode");
```

I build the application according to the parameter. I.e. parameter `a1` shows only module `a1`, parameter `a2` only module `a2`,... and parameter `normal` the whole application. However I have a problem with the `browser cache` especially on parameter "`normal`". After running first time with this parameter, all the next times the browser does not "realize" a new request and shows the application from the cache, meaning the last module showed. Strangely on the other parameters I have not yet noticed this problem. Nevertheless, it is still not reliable and in order to make it certainly reliable I have to avoid browser cache. What could be a solution? I have found that one solution is to add a `timestamp` on the url, which must each time change so that it reads always a new url and makes a new request. How could I attach it though in a java application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the appropriate *cache control* headers for your `HttpServletResponse`.

```
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate");
```

If you need to do this for all your pages, better implement this as a `Filter`.